# TypeError for bar plot with custom date range

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, dataframe

I'm attempting to display a dataframe as a bar graph with a custom date range for `xlim`. I'm able to output a graph if I select `kind='line'` but I get the following error message when attempting `kind='bar'`:

```
TypeError: ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

the dataframe looks as follows:

```
df1 = 
     Date         Quantity
0    2010-01-01   1  
1    2010-01-02   0
2    2010-01-03   0
3    2010-01-04   2
4    2010-01-05   3
5    2010-01-06   1
6    2010-01-07   0
7    2010-01-08   1
8    2010-01-09   1
9    2010-01-10   2
10   2010-01-11   0
11   2010-01-12   5
12   2010-01-13   2
13   2010-01-14   1
14   2010-01-15   2
...
```

This works:

```
df1.plot(x='Date', y='Quantity', kind='line', grid=False, legend=False, 
         xlim=['2010-01-01', '2010-01-10'], figsize=(40, 16))
```

but this doesn't

```
    df1.plot(x='Date', y='Quantity', kind='bar', grid=False, legend=False, 
         xlim=['2010-01-01', '2010-01-10'], figsize=(40, 16))
```

Yet if I remove `xlim` from `kind='bar'` I produce an output. It would be nice to be able to output a bar graph with a custom x range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about an alternative approach - filtering your data **before** plotting?

```
In [10]: df.set_index('Date').ix['2010-01-01' : '2010-01-10']
Out[10]:
            Quantity
Date
2010-01-01         1
2010-01-02         0
2010-01-03         0
2010-01-04         2
2010-01-05         3
2010-01-06         1
2010-01-07         0
2010-01-08         1
2010-01-09         1
2010-01-10         2

In [11]: df.set_index('Date').ix['2010-01-01' : '2010-01-10', 'Quantity'].plot.bar(grid=False, legend=False)
```

Comment: The solution works, but I have to `drop` all other irrelevant columns otherwise they plot. For what I need, this is what I've been looking for.

Comment: @Lukasz, you can do it this way: `df.set_index('Date').ix['2010-01-01' : '2010-01-10', 'Quantity'].plot...` instead of dropping other columns...